# Displaying text under mouse cursor using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am reading an image using OpenCV. It looks like when I click on a pixel then I could display the pixel coordinates and info using the `cv2.setMouseCallback()` function. I want to display those info right under the mouse cursor.

I searched Google and it looks like I need to use GUI libraries. Is there a similar function in OpenCV?

Comment: you have to use pyQt along with OpenCV. OpenCV will handle images. Qt is for GUI work

Comment: You mean coordinates keep updating while you move the mouse or are impressed close to the point where and when you click?

Comment: Yes, I am wondering if there is some kind of tooltip feature inside the opencv. Ive been reading the docs and found none.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is not impossible, but you do not want to do it. OpenCV can display an image, so you would have to draw anything you need into the image and display the new image in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try matplotlib, because what you want(coordinates and values) is already satisfied in that.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I much as I would like to use pyplot for convenience but it does not fit my requirements.